# Creating clear/reset button for my Checkboxes (java awt)

Tags: java, checkbox, awt

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class quiz2 extends Frame implements ItemListener, ActionListener{
Label label1 = new Label("Please Choose one");
Checkbox sugar = new Checkbox ("Sugar");
Checkbox candy = new Checkbox ("Candy");
Button sum = new Button ("Clear");
public quiz2 (){
    setSize (200,200);
    setLocation (100,100);
    setTitle ("Example");
    setLayout (null);
    setResizable (false);
    setVisible (true);

    label1.setBounds (20,20,120,20);
    add(label1);

    CheckboxGroup sweets = new CheckboxGroup();

    sugar.setBounds(20,40,120,20);
    sugar.addItemListener(this);
    add(sugar);
    candy.setBounds(20,60,120,20);
    candy.addItemListener(this);
    add(candy);
    sum.setBounds(20,80,50,30);
    sum.addActionListener(this);
    add(sum);}
public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent item){
    if (item.getSource()==sugar){
        if (item.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        setTitle ("You clicked sugar");}
        else if (item.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
        setTitle("You uncliked sugar");}}
    else if (item.getSource()==candy){
        if (item.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        setTitle ("You clicked candy");}
        else if (item.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
        setTitle("You uncliked candy");}}}
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent butt){
    setTitle("Example");
    candy.setSelected(false);
    sugar.setSelected(false);}}
```

The only solution I found is `checkbox.setSelected()` which wont work in my code, i'm using BlueJ (since our school use it).

the main function of the `sum` button(forgot to change the name) is to `DESELECT` both `sugar` and `candy` whether they're clicked or not.

Comment: Why won't setSelected() work for you?

Comment: i dont really understand it but the program says "cannot find symbol - method setSelected(boolean)"

Comment: Ah, I see. Answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling setSelected() on a CheckBox, but CheckBox does not have a setSelected() method. You should either use a Swing JCheckBox which does have a setSelected() method, or you should call the setState() method of CheckBox.

This is all explained in the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Checkbox.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no method called setSelected in java.awt.Checkbox class. It's called setState.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Checkbox.html

void java.awt.Checkbox.setState(boolean state) - Sets the state of this check box to the specified state. The boolean value true indicates the "on" state, and false indicates the "off" state.

```
candy.setState(false);
sugar.setState(false);
```